# mdframed conflicts with \setmainlanguage{arabic}

Tags: mdframed, arabic, fancybox

[image]

I hope someone can help me with my problems. In the code given below, the `mdframed` width is exceeding the page width. This problem is due to `\setmainlanguage{arabic}`. If I set the main language as English, then no problem arises.

When the main language is set to Arabic, then the black line in the frame header and the body is also not complete.

Finally the first page is with black background and the rest is having the background I set.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[papersize={10in,5in},top=0.55in, bottom=-0.1in, left=0.1in, right=0.1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage[framemethod=PSTricks]{mdframed}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[pstricks]{bclogo}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{10 pt}
\usepackage[tight]{minitoc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,positioning,fit,decorations.text,decorations.markings,decorations.shapes,calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
    citecolor={Blue1},%
    filecolor={Blue1},%
    linkcolor={Blue1},%
    urlcolor={Blue1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}

%\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\color{Green1}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{Green1}\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{-0.55in}{-0.15in}
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{LightGoldenrod1}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{LightGoldenrod1}\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{-0.05in}{-0.05in}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{Orange1}\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\color{Orange1}\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{-0.05in}{-0.05in}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\color{SeaGreen1}\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\color{SeaGreen1}\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0in}{-0.05in}{-0.05in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

%\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.07in}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{Yellow1}%
\hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{\textcolor{Cyan1}{\bf Organisation Name}}
\chead{\it \textcolor{Green1}{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textcolor{Yellow1}{\thepage}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{framed}[2][]{%
\vskip0.03in
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={
        \begin{tabular}{rr}
        \hspace{-0.2in}
        $\begin{array}{r}\vspace{-22pt}\\
        \scalebox{1.00}{}\\
        \vspace{-26pt}
        \end{array}$ &
        \hspace{-0.2in}
        $\begin{array}{r}\vspace{-25pt}\\
        \mbox{\textcolor{white}{\large #2}}\\
        \vspace{-28pt}
        \end{array}$
        \end{tabular}
        },
        %skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        %skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        %innerbottommargin=0.01\baselineskip,
        %splittopskip=9pt,
        splitbottomskip=2pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=#1,
        backgroundcolor=#1!20,
        fontcolor=black,
        shadow=false,shadowsize=4pt,
        roundcorner=5,
        everyline=true,
        settings={\captionsetup{font={color=black}}}
    ]%
    \hrule height0pt width\hsize\relax%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<FORCE WIDTH
    %\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%  this should not be necessary??
}{%
    %\end{minipage}%
    \end{mdframed}
\vskip0.03in
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{chap-learnout}{%
\begin{framed}[DeepPink3]
{
%Learning Outcomes From This Chapter
نتائج التعلم من هذا الفصل
}
}
{
\end{framed}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.0em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{4.0em}{3.6em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.4em}{4.5em}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Contents}
\def\cosec{\mathop{\rm cosec}\nolimits}
\def\sech{\mathop{\rm sech}\nolimits}
\pagecolor{black}
%\pagecolor{Red4}
%\color{Ivory1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{Ivory1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyput(-0.951in,-4.035in)
{
\begin{pspicture}(25,12)
\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,fillstyle=crosshatch*,hatchcolor=Firebrick4,hatchwidth=1pt,fillcolor=Red4,framearc=0.03](-0.22,0.13)(25.08,12.75)
\end{pspicture}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{chap-learnout}
في هذا الفصل سوف تتعلم عن بعض من اللبنات الأساسية للرياضيات.
فضلا عن أن يصبح معتادا على تدوين والرموز المستخدمة في الرياضيات لك
سوف تتعلم القواعد الأساسية للعلم الجبر الذي تقوم عليه الكثير من الرياضيات ويستند.
وعلى وجه الخصوص سوف تتعلم حول المؤشرات وكيفية تبسيط التعابير الجبرية،
باستخدام مجموعة متنوعة من النهج: جمع مصطلحات مثل، إزالة الأقواس وعواملها.
وأخيرا، سوف تتعلم كيفية تبديل الصيغ.
\end{chap-learnout}

\newpage
\begin{chap-learnout}
في هذا الفصل سوف تتعلم عن بعض من اللبنات الأساسية للرياضيات.
فضلا عن أن يصبح معتادا على تدوين والرموز المستخدمة في الرياضيات لك
سوف تتعلم القواعد الأساسية للعلم الجبر الذي تقوم عليه الكثير من الرياضيات ويستند.
وعلى وجه الخصوص سوف تتعلم حول المؤشرات وكيفية تبسيط التعابير الجبرية،
باستخدام مجموعة متنوعة من النهج: جمع مصطلحات مثل، إزالة الأقواس وعواملها.
وأخيرا، سوف تتعلم كيفية تبديل الصيغ.
\end{chap-learnout}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your issue please? Which version do you use? Can you try the current version at github?

Comment: I have added the image of the second page. First page is the same content but with black background. I use version v1.6b

Comment: The current version of `mdframed` is 1.8, which is available with your TeX distribution. Maybe an update will fix your issue. With the current development branch I get the required result.

Comment: Thanks Marco. With the update the mdframed problem is fixed. Now only the first page black background problem remains.

Comment: So the issue isn't related to mdframed. It's related to `fancybox` ;-) .. Can you update your answer so that everyone knows what happened.

Comment: No Marco. Problem was with the older version of mdframed. 'fancybox' was a tag added by some moderator as the mdframed looks like a fancybox. After your previous comment, I updated my miktex completely which got me mdframed 1.8 as well. Then it worked without the width exceeding problem. Now only the first page black background problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is too long for a comment.

As discussed in the comments you issue related to `mdframed` can be solved by using the newest version at CTAN.

Your black page has nothing to do with `mdframed` as the following example shows. I am not able to locate the issue inside `fancybox` however it should help.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[papersize={10in,5in},top=0.55in, bottom=-0.1in, left=0.1in, right=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\pagecolor{black}
\fancyput(-0.951in,-4.035in)
{
\begin{pspicture}(25,12)
\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,fillstyle=crosshatch*,hatchcolor=Firebrick4,hatchwidth=1pt,fillcolor=Red4,framearc=0.03](-0.22,0.13)(25.08,12.75)
\end{pspicture}
}
\begin{document}
\color{white}
ads
\newpage
asd
\end{document}
```